# No route matches [POST] - Rails destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, destroy

I am new to RoR and still don't have enough experience on solving the different errors that may appear to me. In this case I am designing a blog where I can post articles. More specifically, my problem is related to deleting these articles.

As far as I know, writing:

```
resources :articles
```

in the *routes* file is an alternative for writing:

```
get "/articles"            #index
post "/articles"           #create
delete "/articles/:id"     #delete
get "/articles/:id"        #show
get "/articles/new"        #new
get "/articles/:id/edit"   #edit
patch "/articles/:id"      #update
put "/articles/:id"        #update
```

When I try to delete an article I get the following error:

### No route matches [POST] "/articles/1"

The code I wrote was:

**View**

```
<% @articles.each do |art| %>
    <%= art.title %>
    <div>
        <%= art.body %> - <%= link_to "Delete", art, method: :delete %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path       
end
```

Comment: In `routes.rb`, you have `resources :articles` or those written routes?

Comment: @Pavan, I wrote resources :articles

Comment: No route matches [POST] "/articles/1" --> It's is sending POST request not delete. & since there is no post routes for "/articles/{id}" it's giving error. 

Note: Some browser do not allow to send delete request.

Comment: Have you restarted your server since adding those routes?

Comment: @hkumar, but I've specified the delete method. Btw I'm using Firefox, and I believe it should allow me to do such requests. And yes, I have restarted the server.

Comment: @hkumar while you are correct and it should be DELETE this is actually a post request to support browser ignorance. When rails generates a DELETE request it submits a POST request with a hidden field in the form and when rails processes the request it looks at this field to determine the requested method and processes it accordingly. This way the browser being used cannot limit this functionality because all browsers support POST. OP BTW patch and put are not both needed and to conform appropriately to HTML standards it should probably be PATCH.

Comment: Can you confirm if your HTML link has this attribute: data-method="delete" ?

Comment: Post the contents of your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file please.

Comment: @GonzaloRobaina, yes it seems so: <a rel="nofollow" data-method="destroy" href="/articles/1">Delete</a>, but it says Destroy, not Delete.

Comment: @jijohnstone, I did not modify anything in that file.

Comment: Are you sure you are requiring rails jquery-ujs file in your application.js (or application.coffee)

Comment: @GonzaloRobaina, yes: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have this in your view:

```
<%= art.body %> - <%= link_to "Delete", art, method: :destroy %>
```

But you actually need:

```
<%= art.body %> - <%= link_to "Delete", art, method: :delete %>
```

I'd advise double-checking this in your app based on your reply to a comment from @GonzaloRobaina.

Comment: @jijhonstone, what I have in my _view_ is `<%= art.body %> - <%= link_to "Delete", art, method: :delete %>`. According to the suggestions of @GonzaloRobaina, I've already checked if the data-method was delete, but instead of that it was destroy. I'm also requiring jquery, and jquery_ujs in the application.js

Comment: You may already be aware but I've seen this as a source of confusion in the past: to clarify, `method: :delete` does not indicate which controller method to execute. It is used by the `jquery-ujs` library to properly handle `DELETE` requests.

Comment: @jijohnstone, replacing delete with destroy gives the same error.

Comment: Do you have your code available on Github or anything like that?

Comment: @jijohnstone, you were right. I tried it one more time and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're missing the correct path in your code. It should work with something like this :)
`<%= link_to "Delete, article_path(art), method: :delete %>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).